# show/hide a button based on the selection of a radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I have two products, if I select ProductA I want the "Add" button to hide, but if I choose ProductB I want both buttons to show again.

How do I achieve that?

```
<input id="option1" value="ProductA" name="radio-group" type="radio">
<label for="option1" class="radio-custom-label">ProductA</label>
<input id="option2" value="ProductB" name="radio-group" type="radio">
<label for="option2" class="radio-custom-label">ProductB</label>

<button id="add">ADD</button>
<button id="buy">BUY</button>

<script>
    const value = document.querySelector('input[name="radio-group"]:checked').value;
    
    if(value === 'ProductA'){
        document.getElementById('add').style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('add').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to put the code inside an event listener that runs when the user clicks on the radio buttons.

Comment: Radio buttons without a `<form>` element ?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input id="option1" value="ProductA" name="radio-group" type="radio">
<label for="option1" class="radio-custom-label">ProductA</label>
<input id="option2" value="ProductB" name="radio-group" type="radio">
<label for="option2" class="radio-custom-label">ProductB</label>

<button id="add">ADD</button>
<button id="buy">BUY</button>

<script>
    const addBtn = document.getElementById('add');
    const radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio-group"]');

    for (const btn of radioBtns) {
      btn.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        if (value === 'ProductA') {
          addBtn.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          addBtn.style.display = 'block';
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

If I understood correctly, see if this is what you want

Comment: Glad I could help. If acceptable, mark the question as completed.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use some CSS...

```css
#option1:checked ~ button#add { display : none }
```

```html
<input id="option1" value="ProductA" name="radio-group" type="radio">
<label for="option1" class="radio-custom-label">ProductA</label>
<input id="option2" value="ProductB" name="radio-group" type="radio">
<label for="option2" class="radio-custom-label">ProductB</label>

<button id="add">ADD</button>
<button id="buy">BUY</button>
```